# React component not re-rendering after dispatch with mapStateToProps and connect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a functional React component that is wired up with Redux's connect() to listen to any changes in my redux store. If a change were to occur, I would need to re-render my page to update the data being displayed on the screen to be accurate with the data in the store.

The data in the redux store is getting updated with no problem. If I forcefully invoke a re-render by clicking on something to cause a re-render, the new data will update on the page. But you can see how this is not practical in any sense

my component that needs to be re-rendered on any store changes, looks like the following:

```js
function Foo1(props) {
const rightTreeData = props.retrievedRData;
const leftTreeData = props.retrievedLData;
...
...
const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    retrievedLData: state.retrievedLData,
    retrievedRData: state.retrievedRData,
    loading: state.loading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo1);
```

my dispatch occurs in a function, inside of another file. This is a function to build my hierarchy

```js
const loadChildren = (
  id: string,
  direction: string,
  retrievedLeftTree,
  retrievedRightTree,
  dispatch
) => {

  fetch(`...`)
    .then((data) => {
      ... 
      ...
      dispatch(UpdateRetrievedData(data, direction));  // <-------
      ... 
      ...
    
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      
    });
 
};
```

Since it is a function and not a react component. I don't believe I am able to hook it up to use connect()

my store looks like the following.

ACTION

```js
export const UpdateRetrievedData = (payload, position) => ({
  type: position === "right" ? "UPDATE_RETRIEVED_DATAR" : "UPDATE_RETRIEVED_DATAL",
  payload: payload,
});
```

REDUCER

```js
const RetrievedLDataReducer = (state = false, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "UPDATE_RETRIEVED_DATAL":
      return payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default RetrievedLDataReducer;
```

some more information:

the dispatch is called on a button click that is nested inside of a hierarchy tree. I am unable to pull this function out and return the data like a regular function since it is baked and rendered into the HTML isolated in the function.

I have tried approaches like using my own observer-like store.subscribe(). This did work but also resulted in getting up to thousands of requests, which eventually would completely freeze the browser.

Comment: One detail in the code caught my attention. You wrote code for UPDATE_RETRIEVED_DATAL in reducer, but not for UPDATE_RETRIEVED_DATAR. in this case, if position is right, reducer will always return the previous state.
Objects with new references must always be sent for Redux to work properly. I don't know the whole code, but maybe you're missing something here.

Comment: @lead.eg I have a separate reducer for UPDATE_RETRIEVED_DATAR. I don't think that this has anything to do with it, unfortunately. redux on its own doesn't re-render when the data gets mutated. i need to figure out a way to re-render the data without using store.subscribe()